# I want to find lines where a specific word appears in a file along with line number and take the line numbers in an array .How to do that in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, find, words

This returns line numbers but they are in a string:

```
grep -n -F -w $word $file | cut -d : -f 1
```

Comment: Are you only searching for ASCII text? Or will you need to search non-ASCII text at some point?

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `awk` for this, rather than `grep` and `cut`.  To get the line numbers into an array, use [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) along with the bash built-in `mapfile` (a synonym for `mapfile` in bash is `readarray` but you get much better & more detailed help in bash from running `help mapfile` than `help readarray`).  For example:

```
mapfile -t array < <(awk -v w="$word" '$0 ~ w {print NR}' "$file")
```

Alternatively, to use a fixed string match rather than a regex match:

```
mapfile -t array < <(awk -v w="$word" 'index($0,w) {print NR}' "$file")
```

Both of these pass the shell variable `$word` to the awk variable `w` via awk's `-v` option, so will be safe no matter what string it contains.  Much safer than using $word in a double-quoted awk script.

Worth noting: if there's more than one input file, you probably want to print `FNR` rather than `NR`.  NR is the cumulative total number of all lines read so far.  FNR is the line number of the **current file** only. (and when I say "line(s)", I really mean "record(s)" because awk is capable of processing more than just plain-text files with newline-separated records)

Comment: ksh has no mapfile/readarray. zsh has had a `$mapfile` special associative array (which is truely doing a `map`ping of `file`s contrary to bash's `mapfile` builtin) long before bash added its `mapfile` builtin though. In any case, it's true `readarray` is a much better name for the builtin. You might be confusing with `typeset` which comes from ksh and in bash was renamed to `declare` (with a `typeset` alias to it).

Comment: Note that the OP is using the `-F` (maps to `index()` in `awk`) and `-w` options for `grep`  and `-n` (hence the `cut -d:`). Also, note that `-v` mangles backslashes.

Comment: As you say, I'm probably mis-remembering it.  I remember that bash got `readarray` from *somewhere* and renamed it to `mapfile`, but I can't say with 100% certainty where it came from.

Comment: re: awk mangling backslashes: maybe so, but embedding shell vars in a double-quoted awk one-liner script is definitely a security hole, even more so than doing the same with sed.

Comment: Yes, the better way is to use `WORD=$word awk ' ... ENVIRON["WORD"]...'`. `awk`'s `ARGV` array can also be used though it's more cumbersome.

Comment: `perl` may be a better choice here with its `-s` and its `\b\Q$word\E\b` to do boundary matching (maybe with `-C` so it works with non-ASCII text).

Comment: yep, or just `export word` and use `ENVIRON["word"]` in awk.   i do the same a lot with perl, because I just really don't like perl's `-s` option, i'd rather use one of the Getopt:: modules.

Answer (score 1):

In `bash` to read the contents of lines into an array, you use `readarray -t` (aka `mapfile`, though that's a misnomer as there's no *mapping* and there's no *file* here and causes confusion with the `zsh/mapfile` module of `zsh` and its `$mapfile` special associative array (which really maps files)):

```
readarray -t array < <(
  grep -nFwe "$word" -- "$file" | cut -d : -f 1
)
```

(you forgot the `--` and/or `-e` and quotes around expansions btw).

Alternatively, you could use the split+glob operator, and since it's all numbers, you can skip disabling glob:

```
IFS=$'\n'
array=( $(grep -nFwe "$word" -- "$file" | cut -d : -f 1) )
```

That has the benefit of preserving the exit status of the pipeline.

In zsh, you can use the `f` parameter expansion flag to split on line`f`eeds without having to modify `$IFS`.

```
array=( ${(f)"$(grep -nFwe "$word" -- "$file" | cut -d : -f 1)" } )
```

Though, the default value of `$IFS` would also work here (and there are few reasons to modify `$IFS` in zsh):

```
array=( $(grep -nFwe "$word" -- "$file" | cut -d : -f 1) )
```

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a misnomer. It *is* mapping a file into an array (and with process substitution in bash on linux, there *is* a file in /dev/fd/). it's just two slightly different ways of looking at the same thing. I dunno if the minor distinction is important enough to rename it, though - that seems like a pointless incompatibility to me.

Comment: @cas, yes it's a one-way mapping. In truth my main objection and why I got annoyed when bash added that in 4.0 is that it used the same name as a module and feature of zsh that was really doing a (two-way) mapping (even uses `mmap()`) and truely of files `$mapfile[file]` maps to the contents of `file`.